# Performance in Reading data to memory java

Tags: java, memory, io, jvm

I am trying to read a 512MB file into java memory. Here is my code:

```
String url_part = "/homes/t1.csv";
File f = new File(url_part);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
    ArrayList<String> mem = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("Start loading.....");
System.gc();
double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
String line = br.readLine();
int count = 0;
while(line!=null){
    line=br.readLine();
    mem.add(line);
    //System.out.println(count);
    count++;
    if(count%500000==0){
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

The file contains 40000000 lines, the performance is totally fine before reading 18500000 lines, but it stucks somewhere after reading about 20000000 lines. (It freezes here, but continue after a long waiting, about 10seconds)

I kept track of the memory use, I found even the totaly file size is just 512 MB, the memory grows about 2GB when running the program. Also, the 8 core CPU keeps working at 100% utils.

I just want to read the file into memory so that later I can access the data I want faster from memory. Am I doing in the right way? THank!

Comment: "I found even the totaly file size is just 512 MB, the memory grows about 2GB when running the program" - that's not a huge surprise. You've got a) the overhead of string objects, arrays etc - if each string is only about 25 characters, that's quite possibly significant; b) assuming the file is encoded in ASCII or some other 1-byte-per-character encoding, you've got a factor of two blow-up just due to the use of UTF-16 in Java.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the reply! But the key is why the program stuck at some point? It read smoothly before, but runs slower and slower then.

Comment: I suspect it's trying to allocate more memory. How much memory does your machine have, and how much did you let Java have? (e.g. java -Xmx4G ...)

Comment: @fTTTTT Garbage collection is another possible culprit.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have in total 16GB, I have tried -Xmx8g before, and it works. However, I also tried, INSTEAD OF using arraylist, I create a fixed string array of size 40000000. Theoritically, no matter whether it is allocating the memory or not, a fixed string array should not be affected. But the truth is the string array one still got the same behaviour if I don't put the -Xmx flag. Any idea?

Comment: @biziclop It is bit unlikely for the answer, because the GC is called only once at the beginning of the program.

Comment: I still think you shouldn't read the entire file into memory as a string in the first place, seeing as you're dealing with a csv file.

Comment: @biziclop Regarding the XY problem. So you mean I have a better way of storing the data into memory?

Comment: @biziclop So the key is to read the file as a byte buffer etc? If I understand correctly?

Comment: @fTTTTT Yes. If we're talking about structured data, there are plenty of alternatives, starting from a database (embedded or external), or simply parsing the lines into more efficient Java structures.

Comment: "because the GC is called only once at the beginning of the program" - no, that's not true. That may be the only time the GC can actually collect anything, but it will get involved a lot while the VM finds appropriate memory. Don't forget that there's still the memory involved for allocating each string, as well as the array. Use `java -verbose:gc` to see more information.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks, but database is not allowed for the current stage, neither parsing the line(assumes the line contains whole necessary information). The possible way is to change the data structure into byte buffer. But, what is the difference? Different Serialization resulting in smaller store?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are right, since the memory is busy now. But how can I avoid this?

Comment: Allocate a lot of memory, basically. If you know details of the line lengths (e.g. "every line is 25 characters") you *may* be able to write your own `BufferedReader.readLine` implementation which is more memory efficient...

Comment: Another thing you can do is give your `ArrayList` a large initial capacity. `ArrayList`s are created with a very small initial capacity by default (I think it's 10 elements) and every time you exceed capacity, it is increased by a factor of 1.5, requiring copying the entire backing array to the new location.

Comment: What are the startup parameters you're using for your JVM? You might be reaching the limit of your Old gen by tenuring objects prematurely, so full GC must run.

Comment: I have not use any params for the JVM, but later I used -Xms8g with -Xmx8g. It works considerably better but it is the reason that still confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

First, Java stores strings in UTF-16, so if your input file contains mostly latin-1 symbols, then you will need twice more memory to store these symbols, thus 1Gb is used to store the chars. Second, there's an overhead per each line. We may roughly estimate it:

- Reference from `ArrayList` to `String` - 4 bytes (assuming compressed oops)
- Reference from `String` to `char[]` array - 4 bytes
- `String` object header - at least 8 bytes
- `hash` String field (to store hashCode) - 4 bytes
- `char[]` object header - at least 8 bytes
- `char[]` array length - 4 bytes

So in total at least 32 bytes will be wasted per each line. Usually it's more as objects must be padded. So for 20_000_000 lines you have at least 640_000_000 bytes overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the answering. But under such case, what would be the best solution to store efficiently an array of string object?

Comment: Usually nobody stores such big files in the memory. You probably should process it line-by-line or by chunks or import into some DBMS and use DBMS queries to process it.